# normalizing pandas df with stacking level values together

Tags: python, pandas, stack, normalize

I have the following pandas df and I would like to normalize it:

```
df
    id         technology  co2_var  co2_fix  eta_elec 
0    1            lignite  0.39960   17.610     0.434
1    2          hard_coal  0.33012   11.660     0.390
```

normalized df should look like following:

```
df_norm
    id         technology  parameter     value   unit 
0    1            lignite    co2_var   0.39960   
1    2            lignite    co2_fix    17.610          
2    3            lignite   eta_elec     0.434   
3    4          hard_coal    co2_var   0.33012
4    5          hard_coal    co2_fix    11.660
5    6          hard_coal   eta_elec     0.390
```

so level values (after `technology`) of `df` should be stacked in a level called `parameter`, the values of them should be placed under level `value`, and a new level `unit` should be created empty.

**How can I do that?**

@W-B ty for `df.melt(['id', 'technology']).assign(unit='')`

```
     id         technology  variable    value   unit
0     1            lignite   co2_var  0.39960     
1     2          hard_coal   co2_var  0.33012
2     1            lignite   co2_fix ...   
3     2          hard_coal   co2_fix ...
```

**Problems:**

Same id numbers and actually this orders the df in respect to variable(parameter) not respect to technology

Comment: `df.melt(['id','technology'])
`

Comment: wow it does actually almost everything I wanted. last thing would be adding an empty level `unit`, also id should be reseted and set from 1 to len(df.rows)

Comment: df.melt(['id','technology']).assign(unit='')

Comment: @W-B ty and updated question

Comment: Let me add it as a answer .

Comment: @W-B check the problems first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.melt(['id', 'technology']).assign(unit='').sort_values(['id','technology'])
df.id=np.arange(len(df))+1
```

Comment: 1 question if I wanted to reset `id` from 1 to len(df.rows) how would I do it?